# how to export all numbers that are unique in a few text files into another file?

Tags: command-line, grep, csv, output

I have `a.txt`,`b.txt`,`c.txt`. Each has different numbers as below:

**a.txt:**

```
12
14
111
1
15
2
```

**b.txt**

```
12
18
22
23
1
2
```

**c.txt**

```
12
14
15
16
17
1200
```

The output should contain all the numbers from each file, but without any duplication. Is there a command to export such a thing into a text file? The actual text files include hundreds of rows.

Comment: You say csv but *there are no commas in there* !

Comment: My bad. Its actually a text file. each line separated by \n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this if there are more number of files,

```
grep '' *.csv | cut -d: -f2 | sort -u > output.csv
```

Comment: How this line makes output unique?

Comment: sort -u command makes unique output.

Comment: What does `grep` do?

Comment: Grep prints all the contents of all csv files presentinside the current directory along with the filenames.cut part further cutdown the filenames leaving only the content.

Comment: Two completely unneeded processes spawned just to make `sort` read several files? A bit overkillish.

Answer (score 5):

You say that your files are csv i.e. Comma Separated Values but the examples you give are new-line separated. You can do

```
cat a.csv b.csv c.csv | sort -u > output.csv
```

Comment: Its hard to tell with his output, but I presume there aren't really newlines and they're actually comma separated. Try `cat ...|tr , \\n|sort -u|tr \\n , >out`

Comment: How do you make it unique?

Comment: The `-u` switch in `sort -u` makes it unique.

Answer (score 2):

For POSIX compatible implementations of [`sort`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/) all you need is:

```
sort -u *.txt > output.uniq
```

for `sed` will concatenate the files before sorting.